# CIAreaHistogram inputScale factor

Tags: histogram, core-image, cifilter, color-management

I'm building an application that uses the `CIAreaHistogram` Core Image filter. I use an `inputCount` value (number of buckets) of 10 for testing, and an `inputScale` value of 1.

I get the `CIImage` for the histogram itself, which I then run through a custom kernel (see end of post) to set alpha values to 1 (since otherwise the alpha value from the histogram calculations is premultiplied) and then convert it to an `NSBitmapImageRep`.

I then scan through the image rep's buffer and print the RGB values (skipping the alpha values). However, when I do this, the sum of the R, G, and B values across the 10 do not necessarily add up to 255.

For example, with a fully black image, I apply the histogram, then the custom kernel, and get the following output:

```
RGB: 255 255 255
RGB: 0 0 0
RGB: 0 0 0
RGB: 0 0 0
RGB: 0 0 0
RGB: 0 0 0
RGB: 0 0 0
RGB: 0 0 0
RGB: 0 0 0
RGB: 0 0 0
```

This is as I expect, since all pixels are black, so everything is in the first bucket. However, if I run the same algorithm with a color image, I get the following:

```
RGB: 98 76 81
RGB: 164 97 87
RGB: 136 161 69
RGB: 100 156 135
RGB: 80 85 185
RGB: 43 34 45
RGB: 31 19 8
RGB: 19 7 3
RGB: 12 5 2
RGB: 16 11 11
```

Add up the values for R, G, and B - they don't add up to 255. This causes problems because I need to compare two of these histograms, and my algorithm expects the sums to be between 0 and 255. I could obviously scale these values, but I want to avoid that extra step for performance reasons.

I noticed something else interesting that might give some clue as to why this is happening. In my custom kernel, I simply set the alpha value to 1. I tried a second kernel (see end of post) that sets all pixels to red. Clearly, green and blue values are zero. However, I get this result when checking the values from the bitmap rep:

```
RGB: 255 43 25
```

But I just set G and B to zero! This seems to be part of the problem, which indicates color management. But since I explicitly set the values in the kernel, there's only one block of code where this can be happening - the conversion to an NSBitmapImageRep from the CIImage from the filter:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCIImage:kernelOutput];
unsigned char *buf = [bitmapRep bitmapData];
```

Once I set the pixels to RGB 255 0 0, then execute those lines, then read the buffer, the RGB values are all 255 43 25. I have further tried setting the color space of the original CGImageRef on which the entire workflow is based to `kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB`, thinking the color profile may be carrying through, but to no avail.

Can anyone tell me why a `CIFilter` kernel would behave this way, and how I could solve it?

As mentioned before, here are copies of the CIFilter kernel functions I use. First, the one that sets alpha to 1:

```
kernel vec4 adjustHistogram(sampler src)
{
    vec4 pix = sample(src, destCoord());
    pix.a = 1.0;
    return pix;
}
```

And next, the one that sets all pixels to RGB 255 0 0 but that ends up 255 43 25 once it converts to `NSBitmapImageRep`:

```
kernel vec4 adjustHistogram(sampler src)
{
    vec4 pix = sample(src, destCoord());
    pix.r = 1.0; pix.g = 0.0; pix.b = 0.0;
    pix.a = 1.0;
    return pix;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one line of code to generate and display a histogram when using a custom Core Image filter (or whenever you are creating a new CIImage object or are replacing an existing one):

```
return [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHistogramDisplayFilter" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, self.inputImage, @"inputHeight", @100.0, @"inputHighLimit", @1.0, @"inputLowLimit", @0.0, nil].outputImage;
```