# How to make use of kCIFormatRGBAh to get half floats on iOS with Core Image?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, ciimage

I'm trying to get the per-pixel RGBA values for a `CIImage` in floating point.

I expect the following to work, using `CIContext` and rendering as `kCIFormatRGBAh`, but the output is all zeroes. Otherwise my next step would be converting from half floats to full.

What am I doing wrong? I've also tried this in Objective-C and get the same result.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "test")!
let sourceImage = CIImage(CGImage: image.CGImage)

let context = CIContext(options: [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: NSNull()])
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let bounds = sourceImage.extent()
let bytesPerPixel: UInt = 8
let format = kCIFormatRGBAh

let rowBytes = Int(bytesPerPixel * UInt(bounds.size.width))
let totalBytes = UInt(rowBytes * Int(bounds.size.height))
var bitmap = calloc(totalBytes, UInt(sizeof(UInt8)))

context.render(sourceImage, toBitmap: bitmap, rowBytes: rowBytes, bounds: bounds, format: format, colorSpace: colorSpace)

let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bitmap), count: Int(totalBytes))

for (var i = 0; i < Int(totalBytes); i += 2) {
    println("half float :: left: \(bytes[i]) / right: \(bytes[i + 1])")
    // prints all zeroes!
}

free(bitmap)
```

Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237297/how-to-get-meaningful-ciareahistogram-output) about getting the output of `CIAreaHistogram`, which is why I want floating point values rather than integer, but I can't seem to make `kCIFormatRGBAh` work on any `CIImage` regardless of its origin, filter output or otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two constraints on using RGBAh with `[CIContext render:toBitmap:rowBytes:bounds:format:colorSpace:]` on iOS

1. the rowBytes must be a multiple of 8 bytes
2. calling it under simulator is not supported

These constraints come from the behavior of OpenGLES with RGBAh on iOS.